# Algorithm to minimise the sum of products of leaf values and their depth

Tags: algorithm, optimization, binary-tree

I'm stuck with a computer science problem I'm trying to solve. Suppose you have a binary tree (which does not need to be balanced), where each node has at most two child nodes and where only a leaf can contain an integer value (the root and the middle nodes do not). We are given an array of values and have to construct such a tree with the constraint:

= min ∑<sub><sub>=1</sub></sub>

Where  is the value of the array element  and  is the depth of that element. The sum of these products should be minimised.

How do I write an algorithm with the runtime log() that constructs such a tree?

Comment: Seems similar to Huffman coding where `A` is the frequency array.

Comment: Thanks @trincot for the edit. How do I use Tex in Stack Overflow though?

Comment: Sadly, there is no support for Tex on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, I never thought of that! I'll check it out

Comment: @trincot but how did you manage to include Tex symbols in your edit?

Comment: The unicode character set is large ;-) And you *can* use `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags. Just click the edit link as if you were going to edit your post, and you can see how it was typed.

Comment: Are the values all positive ?

Comment: Yes the values must be positive integers

Comment: Agree with @user3386109, this is either Huffman or the [optimal binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree) problem depending on whether it is permissible to reorder the leaves relative to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user3386109 suggests in comments, this is exactly the problem of finding an optimal prefix-free code for a set of symbols given their counts.

[Huffman Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is simple, and known to be optimal:

- Start with a singleton tree for each value
- Repeatedly join the two trees with the smallest total value, until you have only one tree left.

To prove this is optimal, consider that:

- No matter what the shape of your tree is, the deepest level will always contain at least 2 leaves that share a parent
- It would be optimal to assign the smallest two values to those leaves

Therefore, joining the smallest two values is always an optimal decision.  The remainder of the connections can then be made by solving a smaller instance of the same problem:

Let's say that you join values *a* and *b*.  The the cost of placing the new parent at depth *d* then becomes (a+b)*(d+1) = d(a+b) + a + b.  The constant a+b can then be subtracted from all possible solutions.